# IndexPath is returning nil, only on iOS 13.5.1 for indexPathForRowAtPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c

IndexPath is returning nil, only on iOS 13.5.1, other iOS version is getting correct indexPath for specific button position.
Is anyone facing with same issue, or have any solution.
Thanks

```
- (void)deleteTapped:(id)sender {
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
}
```

Comment: When it's happening, what's the value of `buttonPosition`, and `tableView.frame`?

Comment: buttonPosition = (x = 239, y = 1274.6698577072093)
Same position works on other versions of iOS, older than iOS 13.5.1.

tableViewFrame = origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 414, height = 611)